# Removing <tr> from table without :contains()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay,

This may sound easier than it is, I need to use either Javascript or jQuery to remove a `<tr>` from a table, I don't know what row this `<tr>` will be, nor do i know which `<tr>` I will be removing and the only way I can find out which `<tr>` to remove is from the text inside the child's `<td>`.

I cannot use the :contains() selector from jQuery as I'm using ajax to get the elements and it just seems broken.

```
$("td:contains(var)").parent().remove();
```

just gives me a DOMexception error.

Is there a way I can loop through all the `<td>`'s in a table and check the text contents of them?

Comment: what is the exact error? what does ajax have to do with this? is the element in the response? Provide a [mcve] demo

Comment: What seems broken, `:contains()`, `jQuery`, `ajax`? Can you provide a snippet so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: I just assumed that I can't use the :contains(var) selector because I used AJAX to import the elements into the document, and I'm getting an error with a correct syntax, the same reason i can use $(this).hover(function(){} on elements i important through ajax

Comment: shouldn't make any difference that elements were inserted using ajax if they are indeed in the DOM. Nothing in that `:contains` selector should throw error. If jQuery doesn't find a match it will fail silently

Comment: What i tried to accomplish has been resolved with an each() but I'm still interested in why :contains() selector isn't working then.

Comment: provide demo that shows it not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will check the text of each one:

```
$('tr').each(function() {
  var $tds = $(this).find('td');
  $tds.each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === "some text") {
      $(this).parent().remove()
    }
  });     
})
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `.remove();`

Comment: Yes, sorry.  Fixed.

Comment: jquery.min.js:2 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <td> - I cant see why this would be on my end